# Worst case of traversing non-binary tree

Tags: algorithm, tree, time-complexity, big-o

I've written a recursive algorithm that traverses a non-binary tree structure. The structure is consists of directories or files.

The algorithm takes an input directory (`curDirectory`) and traverses the tree depth first. When it reaches the bottom of a branch, it looks for files and prints some info. It then returns one level, looks for files and prints stuff, and so on. We don't know the number of subdirectories or files in a directory.

How do I analyze the worst and average case time for this algorithm?

```
for(int i = 0; i < curDirectory.getChildren().size(); i++){
        if (curDirectory.getChildren().get(i) instanceof INodeDirectory)
            blockCounter = blockCounter + digAndCount((INodeDirectory)curDirectory.getChildren().get(i));
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < curDirectory.getChildren().size(); i++){
        if (curDirectory.getChildren().get(i) instanceof INodeFile) {
            // print stuff and do other stuff 
        }
    }
```

Comment: Best and worst with respect to what?

Comment: Time complexity, added it to my question.

Comment: Yes, but time complexity with respect to what?  Number of files?  Number of directories?  Something else?

Comment: I'm only analyzing for files and directories. Since it's not binary I don't know how many children a directory can have, hence the depth and width is unknown. How do I write the worst and average case time without knowing the depth, width or amount of files in the tree?

Comment: It's theta(n), because you seem to be walking the entire tree. It doesn't matter if it's a binary, trinary, or generally *n*-ary tree or if the tree is balanced or not.

Comment: Not necessarily, the starting folder can be any folder in the tree. The algorithm only accounts for the starting folder and all folders under it, not its parents.

Comment: It's linear in the number of descendants of the provided folder. As @chepner says, it only matters that the directory structure be a tree; it makes no difference what kind of tree. If the directory structure is a graph (eg., with symlinks), then you need a more sophisticated algorithm which is linear in the number of directory entries, rather than the number of actual entities. There is no relationship with the number of files in either case, since you could have an unlimited number of nested directories, with no regular files in any of them.

Comment: It's still theta(n); as far as the algorithm is concerned, the starting folder is the root of its own *n*-node tree. The portion of the tree the algorithm won't visit is irrelevant.

Comment: Could someone write an explanation on how it comes to be theta(n)? I feel like I'm close to getting it but it's not quite clicking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your tree has N directories and M files. When you iterate, every directory and file will be processed once. So the time complexity will be O( M + N ). Or you can decide that the time to process directories and files is about the same, then you could say its O(N).

The structure of the tree doesn't matter. If you had a very deep tree of directories and subdirectories, or a very shallow tree where all the directories are children of the root - every file and every directory gets visited one time.

When you see algorithm that search trees, like balanced binary trees, having complexities that are less than linear - its because its describing a search on that tree that does not visit every node.